# How to filter the logcat by application package name in Android pragmatically?

Tags: android, process, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I have tried following command:

```
// private final String LOGCAT_CMD = "logcat :V *:S";
// private final String LOGCAT_CMD = "logcat | grep ";
// private final String LOGCAT_CMD = "logcat :I com.*****.filterlogcat:V *:S";
```

but its not filter by application package name.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Search your package name at com.user.weatherapp